# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value but value exist

Tags: swift, swifty-json

I know I need to bind my varaible for unwrap but the problem is my value is not reconized but present.

This is my code :

```
surveyW.karmaWin = Int(endedSurvey["karma"].string!)
```

`endedSurvey` is a <del>array</del> **dictionary** of my `JSON` backend. I get a `Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` error. 
I specify that I force the unwrapping to show you my problem.

The problem is my array contains the `karma` value. I show you the screen of the value:

[image]

So we can see that the value existing. Why I get a `Unexpectedly found nil...`?

Comment: If endedSurvey is an array you need to access the element first and then it's key 
endedSurvey[1] will have key value pair of "karma" not endedSurvey.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: @MukulMore it is obvious from screenshot that it's a `Dictionary`, not an `Array`.

Comment: I read his comment saying endedSurvey is an array. so commented that @inokey

Comment: I would recommend to switch from SwiftyJSON to `Decodable`.

Comment: @inokey My bad this is a `Dictionary` !

Comment: But if you want to keep using SwiftyJSON, at least please use it the way it's intended: `.string` is the optional getter, whereas `.stringValue` is the non-optional getter. You should not force unwrap `.string` yourself. Works with other types: .int vs .intValue, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value contained in `"karma"` is not `String`. You're trying to force cast it with SwiftyJSON but it tells you it has a nil. You first need to extract value as it is - `.int`, and after that convert that to something else if needed.

```
surveyW.karmaWin = endedSurvey["karma"].int
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use intValue  because SwiftyJSON has two kinds of "getters" for retrieving values: Optional and non-Optional

.string and .int  are the optional getters for the String and Int representation of a value, so you have to unwrap it before use

> ```
> if let fbId = fbJson["id"].string {
> print(fbId)
> }
> ```
>
> If you are 100% sure that there will always be a value, you can use the equivalent of "force unwrap" by using the non-Optional getter and you don't need if let anymore:

```
let fbId = fbJson["id"].stringValue
```

In your code :

```
surveyW.karmaWin = endedSurvey["karma"].intValue
```

Comment: This work, but what's different between .int and .intValue ?

Comment: .int returns an optional int, which is nil if the value is not a real int. And .intValue provides an int no matter what, which means is tries to convert other values to int values and if that's not possible then it returns a 0.

Answer (score 0):

endedSurvey["karma"] is an Integer not string and also good way to unwrap an optional is:

```
if let karma = endedSurvey["karma"] as? Int{
    surveyW.karmaWin = karma
}
```

Comment: This is SwiftyJSON

Comment: I have given a reply of native feature. Also i want to say that please don't rely on these third party libraries. Native features of apple are awesome and fast.

Comment: SwiftyJSON is a decent piece of software that helped a lot before `Codable` became available in Swift 4. Some use case are easier to write in SwiftyJSON than using `Codable`. Anyway, this question is about SwiftyJSON, therefore answer telling "don't use SwiftyJSON" won't be welcome.